# Fetch only particular key value from a json format in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column which contains the below json formats:

```
{"events": null, "game": "yes", "catch": "yes", "throw": null}

{"events": null, "game": "yes", "catch": "no", "throw": null}
```

print(df_merge['PDH_Value'].head().to_dict())

{0: '{"roth": null, "pretax": null, "catchup": "false", "aftertax": null}', 1: '{"roth": null, "pretax": "true", "catchup": "true", "aftertax": null}', 2: '', 3: '{"roth": null, "pretax": "true", "catchup": "true", "aftertax": null}', 4: '{"roth": "true", "pretax": "true", "catchup": "true", "aftertax": "true"}'}

I wanted to iterate and fetch only the catch value ie "yes","no" from the json and store it in the same dataframe column.

**Desired output:**

```
df_merge['PDH_Value']

true

false
```

**Tried the code and getting the below error:**

```
pd.json_normalize(df_merge['PDH_Value'].apply(json.loads))['catch']

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please say the name of the column with JSON data? I tried your version of the code and everything works fine: 

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ['{"events": null, "game": "yes", "catch": "yes", "throw": null}', '{"events": null, "game": "yes", "catch": "no", "throw": null}']})
df['col2'] = pd.json_normalize(df['col'].apply(json.loads))['catch']

df['col2'] has `yes` and `no` values.

Comment: df_merge is my dataframe name.  df_merge['PDH_Value'] is my column name of the dataframe.  I have posted the head of the dict as well in the question.

Comment: As I can see your json does not have `catch` property but has `catchup`. Is it ok?

Comment: Also it look like that not all of rows in dataframe have valid JSON strings in the column. Try to check it out. May be some of them are empty?

Comment: Yes you are right catch and catchup are same.  Some rows  may be empty sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ast import literal_eval
```

Let's start from here:

```
data=df_merge['PDH_Value'].to_dict()
data={k:v.replace('null','"null"') for k,v in data.items()} 
df_merge['PDH_Value']=pd.Series(data)
```

**Explainaiton:**

- In the above code we are converting df_merge['PDH_Value'] to dictionary of strings(the values inside are string)
- Then we are replacing null to "null" inside the string value of dictionary because if we don't do that we can't convert that string to real dict type
- then we are making series of data and assigning that data back to df_merge['PDH_Value']

Then:

```
df_merge['PDH_Value']=df_merge['PDH_Value'].where(df_merge['PDH_Value'].str.startswith('{'),"{'catchup':'None'}")   
    
df_merge['PDH_Value']=df_merge['PDH_Value'].astype(str).map(lambda x:literal_eval(x) if x!='nan' else float('NaN'))
    
df_merge['PDH_Value']=df_merge['PDH_Value'].map(lambda x:x['catchup'])
```

**Explaination:**

- Since the values of df_merge['PDH_Value'] are still string so we are checking If the values inside Series i.e df_merge['PDH_Value'] starts with `{` or not If It starts with `{` then we are not making any change to it but If If It doesn't start then we are replacing it to `"{'catchup':'None'}"`...In other words we are replacing empty character `''` to `"{'catchup':'None'}"` because you are only interested in 'catchup'
- After that making use of astype() we are ensuring that every thing is string and after that passing values to `literal_eval()` via `map()` method so now the strings inside `df_merge['PDH_Value']` are converted to actual dictionary.
- Since it's now actual dictionary so we are grabbing the value of `'catchup'` key via `map()` method

Finally:

```
df_merge['PDH_Value']=df_merge['PDH_Value'].str.title().map({'True':'yes','False':'no','None':float('nan')})
```

**Explaination:**

- Since we are using `str.title()` that's why True and False isin Uppercase T and F(1st letter upercase then rest lowercase)
- Since you just want yes and no and if you are sure that all values inside dict are lowercase then you can remove `str.title()` from the above method,so it becomes:

`df_merge['PDH_Value']=df_merge['PDH_Value'].map({'true':'yes','false':'no','None':float('nan')})`

- Finally we are mapping values via `map()` i.e it's similar to replacing you can also use `replace()` in place of `map()` so we are changing `true` to `yes` and vice versa and `None` to `NaN`

Comment: Tried via map.    Getting an error:                                      df_merge['PDH_Value']=df_merge['PDH_Value'].map(lambda x:x['catchup'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I have added the real data in the question.

Comment: Can you pls explain what we are doing ?

Comment: data={k:v.replace(null,"'null'") for k,v in data.items()}
NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: @Karthikchengalvarayan Then skip this line and proceed further and see if you are getting error or not

Comment: df_merge['PDH_Value']=df_merge['PDH_Value'].astype(str).map(lambda x:literal_eval(x) if x!='nan' else float('NaN'))                                                                                           
raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x16FF59D0>

Comment: KeyError: 'Null'                  
df_merge['PDH_Value']=pd.eval(df_merge['PDH_Value'].str.title())  raise UndefinedVariableError(key, is_local) from err
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'Null' is not defined

Comment: where to change Null='None' ? And then what to change?

Comment: df_merge['PDH_Value']=pd.eval(df_merge['PDH_Value'].str.title())                                       visitor = getattr(self, method)
AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'

Comment: That is what i am doing now. Just one last step. I wanted to change all true to yes and all fase to no from df_merge[PDH_Value]

Comment: Everything is working. But 3 things.  1.  What i have to do If i wanted to maintain null values in catchup key.  2. All my dictionary key and values are in lower case only. How True and False could be Uppercase T and F ?  3. Can you pls explain line by line so i can debug later when needed.

Comment: @Karthikchengalvarayan added explainations...kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Thank you Anurag. I also have null values in my json for catchup key. I wanted to maintain those null values. How can i do that ?

Comment: @Karthikchengalvarayan you can either fill those Null(NaN) or remove NaN's

Comment: I am already doing this. df_merge['PDH_Value'] =  df_merge['PDH_Value'].fillna('')                     But then wherever the json format is null, my output is producing empty. But if i remove the above line, i am getting  the error as " float object is not iterable".

Comment: @Karthikchengalvarayan I think you got your Final output `df_merge['PDH_Value']` so now what you are willing to do with `df_merge['PDH_Value']`?

Comment: I fixed it like this.  df_merge['PDH_Value'] = df_merge['PDH_Value'].fillna('NULL'). Thank you so much for all your help. It really helped a lot. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234418/discussion-between-karthik-chengalvarayan-and-anurag-dabas).

Answer (score 0):

My approach is similar to @Anurag Dabas but with `json.loads`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

# load json data
# empty string and 'null' are valid json values
json_data = {
    "PDH_Value": [
        '{"roth": null, "pretax": null, "catchup": "false", "aftertax": null}', 
        '{"roth": null, "pretax": "true", "catchup": "true", "aftertax": null}',
        '',
        '{"roth": null, "pretax": "true", "catchup": "true", "aftertax": null}',
        '{"roth": "true", "pretax": "true", "catchup": "true", "aftertax": "true"}',
        '{"roth": "true", "pretax": "true", "aftertax": "true"}',
        'null'
    ]}
df_merge = pd.DataFrame(json_data)

# replace empty strings or whitespace strings with NaN...
df_merge['PDH_Value'] = df_merge['PDH_Value'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

# replace NaN-s with valid JSON with null value "catchup"
df_merge['PDH_Value'] = df_merge['PDH_Value'].fillna('{"catchup": null}')

# parse json values in the columns
df_merge['PDH_Value'] = df_merge['PDH_Value'].apply(json.loads)

# select only "catchup" property from the json if `x` is the dict and has `catchup` property 
df_merge['PDH_Value'] = df_merge['PDH_Value'].apply(lambda x: x['catchup'] if type(x) == dict and 'catchup' in x else None)

print(df_merge)

>>>          PDH_Value
>>>   0      false
>>>   1      true
>>>   2      None
>>>   3      true
>>>   4      true
>>>   5      None
>>>   6      None
```

Comment: Is my following code is right ? As i already have the data in the dataframe column called df_merge['PDH_Value']  instead of json_data. In my case how i have to proceed ?                                                                           df_merge['PDH_Value'] = pd.DataFrame(df_merge['PDH_Value'])                                                                Rest all your code.

Comment: @Karthikchengalvarayan nope, you just skip first lines and can use the code from the `# replace empty strings or whitespace strings with NaN...` comment

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()